# A question based on minimal normal subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, normal-subgroups, solvable-groups

While studying Groups from Thomas Hungerford  I was unable to understand reasoning behind a deduction in a proof on page104.

Adding it's image:
[image]

> Question: How does in line 3 of proof of (iii) solvability of $N$ implies $N'\neq N $ and $N$ is abelian.

Note : Minimal Normal Subgroup: It is a non trivial normal subgroup of group $G$ that contains no proper subgroup which is normal in $G.$

> Theorem 7.11
>
> (I) Every subgroup and every homeomorphic image of solvable group is solvable.
>
> (II) If $N$ is a normal subgroup of $G$ such that $N$ and $G/N$ are solvable, then $G$ is solvable.

Kindly help.

Comment: $N$ is soluble so $N<N$. Also, $N'$ is normal in $G$.

Comment: @DavidA.Craven got it thanks!!